# Fitting mapbox divs inside div with navbar in django html template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am following this mapbox example (https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/) and trying to fit it inside a Django web app. I believe my problem is in base.html because in the Mapbox tutorial they do not have a navbar or use template inheritance. base.html may be causing problems because it uses content from Home.html. In my screen shot you can see that the map and sidebar div do not fill the content-section div height wise. The map also only takes up half of the div it is inside of. I have tried many times to figure out the problem but cannot get it.

base.html

```
{% load static %}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS, and other meta html -->
</head>
<body>

<header class="site-header">
  <!-- header for website containing navbar config -->
</header>

<main role="main" class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md" align="center">
    {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
          {{ message }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
 <script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Home.html

```
{% extends "geotracker/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<body>
<div class="content-section">

  <div class='sidebar'>
 <div class='heading'>
  <h1>Our locations</h1>
 </div>
<div id='listings' class='listings'></div>
</div>
<div id='map' class='map'> </div>
</div>
<script>

  // This will let you use the .remove() function later on
  if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
  Element.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.parentNode) {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
   }
  };
 }

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myTokenHere';

// This adds the map
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
// container id specified in the HTML
container: 'map',
// style URL
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
// initial position in [long, lat] format
center: [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923],
// initial zoom
zoom: 13,
scrollZoom: false
});

var stores = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -77.043959498405,
        38.903883387232
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "phoneFormatted": "(202) 331-3355",
      "phone": "2023313355",
      "address": "1901 L St. NW",
      "city": "Washington DC",
      "country": "United States",
      "crossStreet": "at 19th St",
      "postalCode": "20036",
      "state": "D.C."
    }
  }]
 };
// This adds the data to the map
map.on('load', function (e) {
    // Add the data to your map as a layer
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "locations",
    "type": "symbol",
    // Add a GeoJSON source containing place coordinates and   information.
    "source": {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": stores
    },
    "layout": {
      "icon-image": "restaurant-15",
      "icon-allow-overlap": true,
    }
  });
    });

// This is where your interactions with the symbol layer used to be
// Now you have interactions with DOM markers instead
stores.features.forEach(function(marker, i) {
// Create an img element for the marker
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = "marker-" + i;
el.className = 'marker';
// Add markers to the map at all points
new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [0, -23]})
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);

el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // 1. Fly to the point
    flyToStore(marker);

    // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
    createPopUp(marker);

    // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
    var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

    e.stopPropagation();
    if (activeItem[0]) {
       activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
    }

    var listing = document.getElementById('listing-' + i);
    listing.classList.add('active');

});
});


function flyToStore(currentFeature) {
map.flyTo({
    center: currentFeature.geometry.coordinates,
    zoom: 15
  });
}

function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
var popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();


var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: false})
      .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML('<h3>Sweetgreen</h3>' +
        '<h4>' + currentFeature.properties.address + '</h4>')
      .addTo(map);
}


function buildLocationList(data) {
for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
  var currentFeature = data.features[i];
  var prop = currentFeature.properties;

  var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
  var listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  listing.className = 'item';
  listing.id = "listing-" + i;

  var link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  link.href = '#';
  link.className = 'title';
  link.dataPosition = i;
  link.innerHTML = prop.address;

  var details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  details.innerHTML = prop.city;
  if (prop.phone) {
    details.innerHTML += ' &middot; ' + prop.phoneFormatted;
  }



  link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Update the currentFeature to the store associated with the clicked link
    var clickedListing = data.features[this.dataPosition];

    // 1. Fly to the point
    flyToStore(clickedListing);

    // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
    createPopUp(clickedListing);

    // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
    var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

    if (activeItem[0]) {
       activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');

  });
 }
}
</script>

<style>

  body {
    color:#404040;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  }

  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }

  .sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    width:33.3333%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .pad2 {
    padding:20px;
  }

  .map {
    position:absolute;
    left:33.3333%;
    width:66.6666%;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size:22px;
    margin:0;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px 2px;
  }

  a {
    color:#404040;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  a:hover {
    color:#101010;
  }

  .heading {
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    min-height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background-color: #00853e;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .listings {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:60px;
  }

  .listings .item {
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .listings .item:last-child { border-bottom:none; }
  .listings .item .title {
    display:block;
    color:#00853e;
    font-weight:700;
  }

  .listings .item .title small { font-weight:400; }
  .listings .item.active .title,
  .listings .item .title:hover { color:#8cc63f; }
  .listings .item.active {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    border-left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background:none;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:#00853e;
    border-radius:0;
  }

  .marker {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    background-image: url(marker.png);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  .clearfix { display:block; }
  .clearfix:after {
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  /* Marker tweaks */
  .mapboxgl-popup {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
    display:none;
  }
  .mapboxgl-popup-content {
    font:400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    width:180px;
  }
  .mapboxgl-popup-content-wrapper {
    padding:1%;
  }
  .mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
    background:#91c949;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-top:-15px;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-weight:400;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup-content div {
    padding:10px;
  }

  .mapboxgl-container .leaflet-marker-icon {
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-content {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
    border-bottom-color: #91c949;
  }

  </style>
 </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Sidebar and Map div inside content-section div
[image: Sidebar and Map div inside content-section div]

Comment: Have you tried adding `height: 100%;` to `.map` in your css? Or giving it a defined height, like `height: 600px;`